# Command Line Drawing Packages for Python

Tags: python

I need to write a program in python which draws shapes to a pre-defined canvas size in a loop. At each iteration of the loopI need to store the canvas as an img (jpg, png, doesn't really matter).

I have been advised to look at matplotlib and pyGame. But I was wondering if there was any specific advantages to either of these approaches?

The other stipulation is that the program will run entirely in the command line, with no display connected to the machine should this make any difference the package selected?

Edit : (based on comments)

I am looking to create a program which generates jpgs based on a vector which id drawn by the software. This is will be running on a server in the background based on the current traffic various sites are reciving. I am trying to automatically generate slideshow infographics (with a new image being generated each timestep) which show how the servers usage varies throughout the day.

Comment: What do you want to draw?  What exactly do you mean by "arbitrary shapes"? (Polygons, lines, bezier curves, images, points, all of the above?)  Will there be a separation of "data" and "drawing" coordinates?

Comment: @ChrisHeadleand Are you looking at making a vector image editing program?

Comment: you have asked for specific advantages for a pygame or matplotlib approach. advantages over what ? . I wish to ask what other approach is being considered. I am pretty sure you will need a graphic package.